# dynamic route with Google directions API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, directions

Initially I have two points on map. One of them being origin and other being destination.

The origin is dragable while destination is fixed.

When drawing the map for first time after page load, I have some default value for origin, while destination point gets value from database.Initial Loading works fine. I am able to draw route between origin and destination.

I draw directions on map using this below function

```
function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
      origin:myLatLng1,
      destination:myLatLng,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Now I have a event listener whenever my origin marker is draged, it gets the new latlong of the new position of orign marker, then I call the same function above to get new route.

```
function togglePos(){
    myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(marker1.getPosition());
    calcRoute();
}
```

This is where I am facing problem, I am not able to redraw new route between the new marked origin and the same old destination.
This is my initialize function if any1 needs it.

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatLng
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var image = 'myimage.png';

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image,
    });
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng1,
          map: map,
          draggable: true
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', togglePos);

    calcRoute();
}
```

I am not getting any javascript error.
I am building something like this.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

But instead of selecting it from drop down box, I am calling the function when marker is moved.

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/FvqAL/4/
But i have no idea why its not working on fiddle :|

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that exhibits the problem?  Or a link to the page that does?

Comment: added, please check it.

Comment: Fixed the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvqAL/8/), not sure I understand the issue.  When the destination is the middle of nowhere, the directions service returns ZERO_RESULTS and no route is shown.

Comment: I have updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvqAL/9/), now it does show results, but after moving the marker, it shows zero_results error.

Comment: if I dont use suppressMarkers in renderOptions1, I get two markers, I want one of them to be fixed and other to be moveable. dragable property in renderOptions1 allows you to make both dragable, but there is no property which allows you to fix only one. So I used suppressmarkers, and placed my own markers(one of them is dragable).  I want to make one of them dragable and when it is draged, the new route is calculated and it is displayed on map.

Comment: After the first time, the origin point is not valid [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvqAL/11/)

Comment: geocodezip, its giving me zero_results error in updated one.

Comment: I thought you figured it out.  Look below the map, after the marker is dragged the origin is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in calc route, now whenever it is called, it get marker1 position and draw route through it.

```
function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
      origin:marker1.getPosition(),
      destination:myLatLng,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is final [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvqAL/10/) if you want to check it out.
Thanks for helping :)